# How to convert accel data to quaternion?

Tags: accelerometer, quaternion

To ask my question better, let's assume that I have created 2 different accel data:

| timestamp | accel_x (m/s^2) | accel_y (m/s^2) | accel_z (m/s^2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0009314967509892153 | 0.004056761742037966 | -9.786768386253613 |
| 2 | -0.001326280741200904 | 4.6021665313014 | -5.787749171323297 |

1-) It is possible to infer the orientation using g-force from a stationary accel sensor. Considering that the sensor data above were measured at a moment of non-accelerated motion, how do I convert these measurements into quaternions?

2-) How do I calculate the angle change between the two measurements above with quaternions?

3-) Suppose I convert the 1st measurement into quaternions. How do I rotate this quaternion 60 degrees around the roll axis?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.